# Answer looks like link-only but is valid IMO

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I've failed a review yesterday on this one https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/18215373

While I see how on a first glance this is a link-only answer, on reading the question it really does seem like the problem is that the plugin is not purchased and the solution is... to purchase it. Just like the answer says.

Comment: Is that a programming problem?

Comment: If you'd have clicked the link and have done some research, you would've seen that the plugin in fact is free, and this links to a commercial plugin-plugin (it extends the functionality of the plugin) that only removes that footer. That's not only a link-only answer, but spam, and should certainly be removed from the website. If someone has a programming problem, _buy this product that fixes it_ without any context is NOT an acceptable answer.

Comment: That is a good point @ErikvonAsmuth, if you write it up as an answer I'll accept it. Lesson learned.

Comment: @vektor I would've done that, but can't answer the question since it's closed

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I mean here on Meta.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth "buy this product that fixes it without any context is NOT an acceptable answer" Sure it is.  "Buy this product that has nothing at all to do with your question" is spam.  "Buy this product that solves the problem you asked about" is an answer to the question.  You may not like it, but it's an answer.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not familiar with this field, but assuming that the solution is indeed purchasing the plugin, the answer could definitely be more detailed, and not just "buy it".

In this specific case, I think that the question itself should be closed.